# Extracting numerical data from string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have text data in a csv file in this format:

> 76.76% @ 26.2° C D: 20.7° C G/KG: 15.5
>
> Date,Value,Formatted Value
>
> 2019-10-11 14:50:00,71.19,71.19% @ 24.4° C D: 17.7° C G/KG: 12.8
>
> 2019-10-11 15:00:00,72.2,72.2% @ 24.4° C D: 17.9° C G/KG: 13
>
> 2019-10-11 15:10:00,71.35,71.35% @ 24.4° C D: 17.8° C G/KG: 12.9

I would like to extract the each numerical data and store it in a different column. The numbers don't always contain a decimal place though.

Edit: The data is from a csv file and I would like to store each numerical data in a different column.

Comment: can you provide some more data?

Comment: @luigigi, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example i get the data as string and used `split(' ')`. You can use `sep=' '` for get data from csv file. Also i've used regex you need the import it as `import re`

```
data = '76.76% @ 26.2° C D: 20.7° C G/KG: 15.5'
data = data.split(' ')
data = [re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", x) for x in data]
data = [x for x in data if x != '']

temp_dict = {}
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    temp_dict[f'col_{i}'] = item

df = pd.DataFrame([temp_dict])
```

Output:

```
   col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3
0  76.76  26.2  20.7  15.5
```

---

Update

This can be more useful.

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']] = df['Formatted Value'].str.extractall('(\d+.\d+)').unstack().loc[:, 0]
```

---

Update 2

This code works with decimal and int values.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
my_list = df['Formatted Value'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'[\d\.\d]+', x))
d = {'Extractted': my_list}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']] = pd.DataFrame(temp_df['Extractted'].values.tolist(), index=temp_df.index)
```

Comment: I used it, however when the data does not have any decimal place, it skips the data.
> 80.01% @ 24.7° C D: 20° C G/KG: 14.8
It misses the 20 C.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Can you try Update 2? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` here.

```
import re
a='76.76% @ 26.2° C D: 20.7° C G/KG: 15.5 75' #I added 75 just to show it caputres ints and floats.
nums=re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+',a)
print(nums)
#['76.76', '26.2', '20.7', '15.5', '75']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.join(df['Formatted Value'].str.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+').str.join(' ').str.split(expand=True)).drop('Formatted Value',axis=1)

                  Date  Value      0     1     2     3
0  2019-10-11 14:50:00  71.19  71.19  24.4  17.7  12.8
1  2019-10-11 15:00:00  72.20   72.2  24.4  17.9    13
2  2019-10-11 15:10:00  71.35  71.35  24.4  17.8  12.9
```